# windows Clipboard to webpage textbox control

Tags: c#, windows, html, asp.net-mvc-3, clipboarddata

I have a mvc project where i have created some controls with HTML5 and bind the same to the respective view. There are lots of textbox controls inside that webpage .When i am doing some testing it is a waste of time to give inputs for all text box without which i can't proceed further since validation present with all textbox controls.

Desired solution ::we will have a c# desktop application which will have some dummy values for each controls of that webpage . The same desktop application would have a copy button which helps to copy all the values in to windows clip board . Now i don't have any clue how to pass those values to that particular webpage controls after it get loaded inside the chrome browser.

I am very new to mvc and web , so could not able to get where should i start to resolve the above issue.Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try [zeroclipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) library.

Comment: Alternatively you can have your form act as a keyboard, and type in the values, using tab to cycle through the fields.  There is an 'InputManager Library' that can help.  But there are various debugging tools that already exist to prefill forms for you.

Comment: @wholesRich - Can you please give some more inputs . Some  reference would be helpful .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at some chrome plugins to help you with testing forms. Maybe something like [form-filler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo) or [junkfill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/junkfill/cajejbcjfkhgmfbapmhopccephhjedeb) can help you.

Comment: Can you please give somemore input . Some  reference would be helpful .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anywhere i can get source code for the above 2 mentioned tools ?